# NoClassDefFoundError in JavaFX app

Tags: java, javafx

Why I have the following exception when I start my javafx application?

```
Glass detected outstanding Java exception at -[GlassViewDelegate sendJavaMouseEvent:]:src/com/sun/mat/ui/GlassViewDelegate.m:541
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap
```

I have beanutils in the pom.xml and in the idea project configuration.

I start application like console app

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("fxml/main.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    stage.show();
}
}
```

upd: looks like this lib is missing in classpath

Answer (score 0):

It was simple =)
In started module my lib was marked with "exclusion" in pom.xml